# WordPress REST API application password authentication in Javascript - risk?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm utilizing the WordPress REST API to create posts within my application. Currently, the username and password are stored in a regular JavaScript file. My intention is to restrict this user to only have permissions for post creation. However, I'm concerned about the potential security risks of having these credentials exposed in this manner.

Is it considered a significant risk to create posts using this method, given the open visibility of this data? Additionally, are there any recommended best practices or alternative approaches to handle authentication securely in such scenarios?

```
const username = 'creator';
const password = '30LI lgKe S3k2 mLGG yYXt FOiL';

fetch("/wp-json/wp/v2/posts", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(username + ':' + password),
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        title: "Title",
        content: "My Content",
        status: "draft"
    })
});
```

Comment: In this case, you simply have no protection. So, "no risk". Simply, everyone has access to the resource.

Answer (score 0):

Hard-coding credentials in this manner is clearly not secure. Everyone can steal them.

Is your front end application located inside Wordpress? If yes, I suggest you switch to [nonces](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#cookie-authentication).

You create the nonce with PHP:

```php
$args = array();
if(is_user_logged_in()){
  $args['wp_rest_nonce'] = wp_create_nonce('wp_rest');
}
wp_localize_script('your-script-name', 'WPURLS', $args);
```

And send it in the ajax request using the header `X-WP-Nonce`

```js
if(typeof WPURLS.wp_rest_nonce !== 'undefined') {
  fetch("/wp-json/wp/v2/posts", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'X-WP-Nonce' : WPURLS.wp_rest_nonce,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        title: "Title",
        content: "My Content",
        status: "draft"
    })
  });
}
```

The endpoint will check the user's authentication and capabilities to perform the requested action.

Note that nonces are extremely secure because they

1. have a predefined duration, beyond which they expire
2. are local to the user and his session

This means that, to breach your application, someone would have to get the nonce and steal both your user's credentials (which you don't have to expose) and his session.